# How to change Outlook e-mail adres

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I've moved to another department in my company and so I want to change my e-mail adres. But when I try to change it Outlook eiher changes it back or blocks me with some stupid non-complaint.

Adding a new E-mail account: I can make a new E-mail account but somehow it always links with the existing data file and the e-mail address remains the old. Also the new e-mail address does not appear.

Trying to remove the existing data file:

Dutch version:

```
Via Bestand->Accountinstellingen->Accountinstellingen...->Gegevensbestanden->de regel met mijn e-mail adres->Verwijderen

Geeft de foutmelding: "Dit gegevens bestand is gekoppeld aan een e-mailaccount. Gebruik het tabblad E-mail als u het gegevensbestand wilt verwijderen."
```

My translation:

```
At File->Accountsettings->AccountSettings...->Data files->The item with my old email address->Remove

Causes the error: "This data file is linked to an e-mail account. Use the tab E-mail when you want to remove the data file".
```

Naturally there is no tab "E-mail"

Note: I already made an alternative data file to choose as default.

Note: I tried removing the pysical files, Outlook just kicks me in the nuts and restores them.

Note: The text is in dutch because Outlook messed up the language, the setting says it should be same as Windows, but my Windows language is English, yet Outlook is in dutch...
Also it's like they designed it specifically to have terrible usability.

Comment: your question does not seem clear, you seem to be doing something which is generally not allowed in an organization (as you said you moved to another department)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm in IT support at a small company and we just changed our name, and therefore changed our email domain name. I've found several different ways to deal with this but here's what seems to be the easiest. Note: If this is an Exchange account, and your IT department hasn't created a different email for you, that's something they have to do on the server side.

1: Make sure Outlook is closed (sometimes it runs in the background and the process must be stopped from the Task Manager.) Open the Control Panel, and search if you must to find "Mail" (or with Outlook 2013, it will probably say "Mail (Microsoft Outlook 2013)").

2: Click "Show Profiles" and create a new profile with your new email. Set it as the default profile to use when starting Outlook.

3: Open Outlook and it should load the fresh new profile with your new email address.

4: Optional - in some cases, you may want to use your existing data file with your new account (if you weren't using IMAP and/or it doesn't automatically download all your emails, for example). To do this, navigate to C:\Users\(your user name)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook. Copy the name of the data file Outlook created for your new profile, and then delete the file and rename the old data file with the exact same name. This is how I dealt with switching email addresses for some of our users who have 20+ GB mailboxes, since it would have taken many hours to download it all.

Comment: I din't understand it at first, but this fixed my problem, without losing any of my saved e-mails. IT at my company also did something, altough that din't do anything at first. Maybe it was the combination of what they did and the steps you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of email account is this? If it's a corporate Exchange mailbox then you can't change your email address from Outlook, all of those settings are controlled on the server so you'd need to speak to your SysAdmins to get it changed.

Within Account Settings the "E-Mail" tab should be the first tab from the left, with Data Files that you say you've tried using being the second tab.

When viewing the E-mail tab you'll see your email address listed on the left, and the type of mailbox it is on the right. That's either going to be "Microsoft Exchange" in which case you can't change this yourself, or either "POP/SMTP" or "MAP/SMTP" in which case you should be able to change the email address that you're sending from via the properties of the email account (though unless your email account is configured at the server end to receive emails for that alternate address you won't receive messages using it).

Comment: It would be better to ask the questions in the comment section since you have a rep level of 50, after you've gotten your required info, proceed to the answer, instead of if this, and if that.

Comment: I'd say he answered the question, regardless of the fact that he also asks questions in his answer.